# edit array in ember.js inside javascript file

Tags: ember.js

I have declared an array in ember as shown below.

```
checkboxList:[{VALUE: "Content", CHECKBOX_ID: 1},{VALUE: "Size", CHECKBOX_ID: 2}],
```

I want to change the value in the first object from 'Content' to 'Contents' in another part of the program.

I tried to do the following :

```
this.set('checkboxList.[0].VALUE', "Cont");
```

But it did not work. Could anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ember set](https://emberjs.com/api/api/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject/set) like this:

```
import {set} from '@ember/object';


set(this.get('checkboxList')[0], "VALUE", "Contents");
```

You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d66c7542fffac3b065cc8bbd03c24ec6) for this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `[]`:

```
this.set('checkboxList.0.VALUE', "Cont");
```

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/2c3bf0366b36f516f733b69de6e4720a?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) is a twiddle showing how this works.